# Confused with this execution style in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" onclick="adsds();">Click Me 2!</button>

</body>
<script>

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){alert('Hello world!') };

function adsds()
{
alert();
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = return false;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me understand this execution. function adsds() doesn't execute but if I remove the 'document.getElementById("btn").onclick = return false;', it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById("btn").onclick = return false;` isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: wow, thanks. When i wrap it over an anon function, it works.

Comment: Which happens to be my answer :D

Comment: now how do i mark it as answer? :D

Comment: There's a "Checkmark" next to the vote count on every answer, click that to accept the answer of your choice. Accepting an answer is possible when the _question_ is at least 15 minutes old. (So, you'd have to check back in ~10)

Comment: Accepting an answer should be unlocked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("btn").onclick = return false;` Isn't valid JavaScript:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `return`

You may want to use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    return false;
};
```

Then, you'll actually return `false`, when the `"btn"` element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Check your debug console, you have syntax error. That's not valid JavaScript code.

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = return false;
```

Read more about [Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Cerbrus is right, or you may just define the function previously:

```
function returnFalse() {
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = returnFalse();`
```